# How to show the process in Python: InsertionSort

Tags: python, python-requests, insertion-sort

I am trying to write python program for **insertion sort** but the problem is I want it to show the process or the round of the process like this but I don't know how.

**input** : `9, 8, 7, 10, 2`

**Data in list** is `[9, 8, 7, 10, 2]`

**Round 1** : 9, 8, 7, 10, 2 
          8, 9, 7, 10, 2

**Round 2** : 8, 9, 7, 10, 2
          7, 9, 8, 10, 2
          7, 8, 9, 10, 2

**Round 3** : 7, 8, 9, 10, 2
          7, 8, 9, 10, 2
          7, 8, 9, 10, 2
          7, 8, 9, 10, 2

**Round 4** : 2, 8, 9, 10, 7
          2, 7, 9, 10, 8
          2, 7, 8, 10, 9
          2, 7, 8,  9, 10

**Sorted array** is : `2, 7, 8, 9, 10`

End of program

I'm really new for this please help me. Thx :)

```
a=[]
i=0
while i<=4:
        a.insert(i,int(input("Enter your number: ")))
        i=i+1
print ('Data in list is',a)
j=1 
while j<=5:
    i=0 
    while i<=3:
        if a[i]>=a[i+1]:
            b=a[i]
            a[i]=a[i+1]
            a[i+1]=b
        i = i+1
    j = j+1

print ('Sorted array is :',a)
print ('End of program:')
```

Comment: Did you try adding some `print`s in one of the loops?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would consider looking into the `for` loop, which is shorthand for exactly what you are doing with the `while`. In regards to your actual question, the key is that you need to print out the round within the loop. So that, as your program is iterating through the `a` list, you can catch the current progress of `a` VIA `print`. See below:

```
a = []
for i in range( 0, 5 ):
    a.insert( i, int( input( "Enter your number: " ) ) )

print( 'Data in list is', a )

for j in range( 1, 6 ):
    for i in range( 0, 4 ):
        if a[ i ] >= a[ i+1 ]:
            b = a[ i ]
            a[ i ] = a[ i+1 ]
            a[ i+1 ] = b
    print( 'Round', j, ':', a )

print ( 'Sorted array is :', a )
print ( 'End of program:' )
```